# Error when trying to convert BufferedImage into int array

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedimage

I am trying to convert my `BufferedImage` into a integer array, but i am getting the following error: "`java.awt.image.DataBufferByte` cannot be cast to `java.awt.image.DataBufferInt`"

Here's my bit of code:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main (String []  args) { 
    BufferedImage img = null;
    try {
      img = ImageIO.read(new File("G.bmp"));
    } catch (IOException e) { }

    int[] imgarray = ((DataBufferInt)img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
byte[] imgarray = ((DataBufferByte)img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

Comment: thanks this works.. now i have a byte array however, but i suppose byte is sufficient :)

Comment: Yes, a byte array is usually utilized to pass any binary data (to a stream, or to create an image from it and vice versa).

Comment: Any idea why this isn't represented as img.getWritableData(), or even just img.buffer? Also, why do we need to separately handle the treatment of every BufferedImage type - isn't there an inheritance-friendly solution?